# Grouping by Count(*) following multiple join operations

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to figure out what I thought was a simple query-

I have the following tables with schemas as follows.

```
models(id: int, first_name: string, last_name: string)

painters(id: int, first_name: string, last_name:string)

portraits_painters(painter_id: int, portrait_id: int)

roles(model_id: int, portrait_id: int)
```

I am trying to satisfy this query: The first name, last name, and count
for painters who have been the model for their own painting- i.e. where the count column for a first and last name is the number of self portraits the painter has done (both the painter and model).  (Safe to assume equal first names and last names mean the same individual).

If a painter has no self portraits they should not even be included in the final output.

```
SELECT
  models.first_name,
  models.last_name,
  COUNT(portraits_painters.portrait_id)
FROM models
RIGHT JOIN painters
  ON models.first_name = painters.first_name
  AND models.last_name = painters.last_name
RIGHT JOIN portraits_painters
  ON portraits_painters.painter_id = painters.id
RIGHT JOIN roles
  ON roles.portrait_id = portraits_painters.portrait_id
GROUP BY portraits_painters.portrait_id;
```

I essentially tried to narrow the table down to rows where names matched, followed by instances where the painter ids matched and the portrait id's matched, but evidently there's something incorrect in how I am joining tables.
I'm also getting errors in regards to the GROUP BY portion, so not sure if there's a better way to approach it? Perhaps aliasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the names of the models and painters using:

```
select m.first_name, m.last_name, p.first_name, p.last_name
from roles r join
     portraits_painters pp
     on pp.portrait_id = r.portrait_id join
     painters p
     on p.id = pp.painter_id join
     models m
     on m.id = r.model_id;
```

The rest is just a `where` and `group by`:

```
select p.first_name, p.last_name, count(*)
from roles r join
     portraits_painters pp
     on pp.portrait_id = r.portrait_id join
     painters p
     on p.id = pp.painter_id join
     models m
     on m.id = r.model_id
where m.first_name = p.first_name and m.last_name = p.last_name
group by p.first_name, p.last_name;
```

I am not sure what thinking leads to outer joins or `exists` clauses.

Comment: this worked excellently, thank you! Just out of curiosity, is this something that has to be done in two separate statements, or is it possible to do in one? Still getting the hang of the style and syntax

Comment: @user7090180 . . . The second query is the correct query.  The first query is to give you guidance on why it works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get painter infos for all portraits:

   `SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, pp.portrait_id 
   FROM portraits_painters AS pp 
   JOIN painters AS p 
   ON pp.painter_id = p.id`
2. Get model infos for all portraits:

   `SELECT m.first_name, m.last_name, pp.portrait_id 
   FROM roles AS r 
   JOIN models AS m ON m.id = r.model_id 
   JOIN portraits_painters AS pp ON pp.portrait_id = r.portrait_id`
3. Combine these two tables on the same first_name and last_name. Now you get both painter infos and model infos for every portrait. Just group the records by first_name and last_name, and `COUNT` for each group, you get what you want.

So, the final query would be:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, COUNT(a.portrait_id) 
FROM
  (
    SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, pp.portrait_id 
    FROM portraits_painters AS pp 
    JOIN painters AS p 
    ON pp.painter_id = p.id
  ) AS a
JOIN
  (
    SELECT m.first_name, m.last_name, pp.portrait_id 
    FROM roles AS r 
    JOIN models AS m ON m.id = r.model_id 
    JOIN portraits_painters AS pp ON pp.portrait_id = r.portrait_id
  ) AS b
ON a.first_name = b.first_name AND a.last_name = b.last_name
GROUP BY a.first_name, a.last_name;
```